# Head and tail by group

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm re-posting this question again after confusion caused on my part, apologies for that. I believe the example now is correct.

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(group=rep(c("A","B","C"),c(8,10,8)), size=c(rep(1000,5),rep(0,3),rep(2000,7),rep(0,3),rep(5000,5),rep(0,3)),
         out=c(rep(0,5),rnorm(3,5,1),rep(0,7),rnorm(3,5,1),rep(0,5),rnorm(3,5,1)),
         g1=rbinom(26,1,.5),g2=rbinom(26,1,.5),g3=rbinom(26,1,.5))


   group size      out g1 g2 g3
1      A 1000 0.000000  0  0  1
2      A 1000 0.000000  0  1  0
3      A 1000 0.000000  0  1  0
4      A 1000 0.000000  0  1  0
5      A 1000 0.000000  0  0  1
6      A    0 3.997360  1  1  0
7      A    0 4.992823  1  0  1
8      A    0 5.644386  1  1  1
9      B 2000 0.000000  1  1  0
10     B 2000 0.000000  0  1  1
11     B 2000 0.000000  0  0  0
12     B 2000 0.000000  1  0  1
13     B 2000 0.000000  1  1  0
14     B 2000 0.000000  1  0  1
15     B 2000 0.000000  1  1  1
16     B    0 5.247895  1  0  0
17     B    0 5.248148  0  0  1
18     B    0 5.026844  1  1  1
19     C 5000 0.000000  0  0  0
20     C 5000 0.000000  0  1  0
21     C 5000 0.000000  0  1  1
22     C 5000 0.000000  0  0  0
23     C 5000 0.000000  1  0  1
24     C    0 6.532156  1  1  0
25     C    0 5.457338  0  0  0
26     C    0 4.675683  1  1  1
```

I would like to obtain this:

```
   group size      out  g1 g2 g3
1      A 1000 0.000000  1  1  1
6      A    0 7.276473  0  0  1
9      B 2000 0.000000  0  0  0
16     B    0 5.630425  1  0  0
19     C 5000 0.000000  0  0  0
24     C    0 5.449923  1  0  1
```

And final output is:

```
   group size      out g1 g2 g3
6      A    0 7.276473  1  1  1
16     B    0 5.630425  0  0  0
24     C    0 5.449923  0  0  0
```

Basically replacing values of g1-g3 in first row (per group) with values in second row per group. I'm looking for base r solution.

The solution is that:

1) select first row per group (row 1) if the out==0 and size>0 and select first row per given group that out!=0 and size==0 (row 2).

2) replace dummy's g1-g3 from first row and replace the second row per group.

3) keep only last row per group.

Here is possible (partial) solution:

```
sol <- with(df, by(df, group, function(x) rbind(head(x[(x$size>0 & x$out==0), ],1),head(x[x$size==0 & x$out!=0, ],1))))
data.frame(do.call(rbind,sol),check.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: It is totally unclear what you are asking based on your input and desired output. Apart from that, you ask us to give you the code. I think you should know by now that it's not how SO works.

Comment: @Masoud: I believe I have provided enough information. Also I'm not asking for "code", but rather neat solution which I believe SO has been build for this purpose.

Comment: The expected output is not even within the dataframe... for example. were did you get `A    0 7.276473  0  0  1` from? I mean even that `7.276473` how did you obtain it?

Comment: @Onyambu See the first sentence in the answer. The data was generated without `set.seed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make a reproducible example, when you use RNGs or `sample`, you should always `set.seed()`.

```
set.seed(5175)

df <- data.frame(group=rep(c("A","B","C"),c(8,10,8)),
size = c(rep(1000,5),rep(0,3),rep(2000,7),rep(0,3),rep(5000,5),rep(0,3)),
out=c(rep(0,5),rnorm(3,5,1),rep(0,7),rnorm(3,5,1),rep(0,5),rnorm(3,5,1)),
g1=rbinom(26,1,.5),
g2=rbinom(26,1,.5),
g3=rbinom(26,1,.5))

fun <- function(x){
    i <- min(which(x$size > 0 & x$out == 0))
    tmp1 <- x[i, ]
    i <- min(which(x$size == 0 & x$out != 0))
    tmp2 <- x[i, ]
    tmp2[, 4:6] <- tmp1[, 4:6]
    tmp2
}

res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$group), fun))
res
```

Comment: @Maximilian I don't understand what you mean by a general full proof. The only hardcoded bit are the `g1-g3` column numbers, `4:6`. Can you make the question more clear?

Comment: I have taken down my comment. There won't be any other answers provided as the question is on hold. Apprently only you understood the question. Thank you.